# Purpose of POM.xml in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am very new to Maven. I have the following questions:

1. Do we need to create POM file our own?Do we need to understand POM file fully to use Maven?
2. We are mentioning Plugin in the POM. will that plugins only be downloaded by Maven when use Maven? or by default all plugins will be downloaded?

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand the [pom content](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) otherwise you are not able to influence the build process. The pom file should be created manually but there are some exceptions like Spring Roo which will create the pom but it's better to understand the pom to see if something is going wrong.

The plugins mentioned in the pom will be downloaded automatically by Maven but there are plugins which are by default in the [life cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) which will be downloaded as well in contradiction to naming them in the pom file.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need at least to understand some basics of Maven: dependencies, how to configure plugins, how to start a new POM (you can [do this in IDE](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_importing_Maven_projects#Creating_a_project_with_a_Maven_module) or [create a project from an archetype](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/simple-project-sect-create-simple.html)), basic commands: `mvn compile`, `mvn  package`, `mvn install`. If your only need is to build your classes into JARs, Maven configuration would be as small as a list of dependencies.
2. Everything in Maven is downloaded by default - all artifacts are being searched in Central and any other configured repositories. Once downloaded, they are stored on your machine at `$HOME/.m2/repository`.

Might be helpful: [Maven Quick-start Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692029/maven-quick-start-guide).