# Import Apache POI into eclipse project and make it useable on another computer

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, apache-poi

Good evening,

I'm designing  program that users would then use on their own computer. I have two questions:

I need to import Apache POI into my libraries, but can't quite find how to do it (I spent 2 hours looking for it on the internet and on StackOverflow, but can't find anything that works).
I am using a Mac with the latest version of both Mac OS and Eclipse, and downloaded poi-4.1.2 from the Apache POI website, but I can't add it to my library.
I'm quite new to this, so I don't really understand how to add libraries (I only managed to add JUnit after following a very thorough guide).

Secondly, given that the users will use the program on their computer, would it be possible for them to use it without downloading Apache POI, or is there a way I can add it straight into the program ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Maven or Gradle. [Maven Quick Start Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692029/maven-quick-start-guide)

Answer (score 1):

External libraries can be imported in your project as dependencies using Maven, Gradle or adding them manually to your Java Project "Build Path".

Since many years we use widely Maven to build projects and it is a great tool. I think it is the best tool I have used to handling dependencies. So I think you can use it too. Learn Maven and you will win many days per months of work on projects deployments, testing and building processes.

Your program will be bundled and all its own dependency. It's up to you to use some Maven plugins to build a fat jar or a more precise work with the assembly plugin.

If you want to distribute your work to people whom don't know how it works, I think a fat jar with all your dependencies included is the best way to go.

Good coding !